# $_GET in Wordpress function.php - Not working

Tags: php, wordpress, function, get

First, thanks for the time. I have been messing with this quite a bit and cannot figure out what is going wrong (and this is something I thought I understood) I am currently trying to change save location of files uploaded via WP. As the title suggests. The $_GET is not pulling anything from -

/?action=type1&project=1&method=add

I can replace the gets with appropriate numbers and get correct project output so I am almost certain the $_GET that isn't pulling the info. As I understand this is a supervariable so should have no problems getting into a function.

Can anyone let me know if they see any problem in my logic, syntax or am I missing something going on in upload_dir/wp_handle_upload_prefilter hook? Or are there any suggestions on troubleshooting/solving?

$_GET is used everywhere on the site and works fine otherwise.

```
function ca_doc_pre_upload($file){
    add_filter('upload_dir', 'ca_doc_custom_upload_dir');
return $file;}

function ca_doc_custom_upload_dir($path){   
    if (isset($_GET['project'])) {
         $projectID = $_GET['project'];
    };

    if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
        $type = $_GET['action'];
    };

    $project = ca_get_project($projectID);
    $customdir = '/'.strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $project->project_name)).'/'.$type;

    $path['path']    = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['path']);
    $path['url']     = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['url']);      
    $path['subdir']  = $customdir;
    $path['path']   .= $customdir; 
    $path['url']    .= $customdir;  

return $path;}

add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'ca_doc_pre_upload', 2);
```

To Confirm not able to retrieve with get. Used.

```
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $type = $_GET['action'];
}else{
$type = 'Not Getting';};
```

And tried to save a file. It saved it to Not getting the folder. (took out the project part).

Some additional information. Created another function in function.php using get and called it on the same page where plupload happens and it worked. The only thing I can figure now it that this isn't working because its called from upload or the hook is doing something... I am only guessing now because I ran out of viable logic a long time ago.

Thanks again for the time.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump( $_GET )` and `var_dump( $_REQUEST )` just to inspect things? It's possible that the `$_GET` elements are being added *after* the hook runs (and therefore won't be available during the hook).

Comment: See now my neophyte is showing. Adding a var_dump in that function makes all kinds of errors when called.

Comment: Did you add it as the first line of your function?

Comment: Function is usually called by a loader and I cant get that to run with the var_dump, so I just pulled the function call into the body and it shows all the gets working, but I guess that doesnt mean anything.

Comment: It's an upload from front or back office?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some other help and research turns out that plupload that handles the upload in Wordpress was doing some AJAX work in the background calling;

```
url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php')?>'
```

And for some reason the $_GETs were not going with that, so just changed the URL to include them as follows, and all was right again.

```
url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php?project='.$_GET["project"].'&action='.$_GET["action"].'') ?>'
```

Apparently when using the hooks above this is the point(admin-ajax.php) in which it grabs the $_GETS

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered the query params with WP `query_vars()`? Perhaps the permalink rewriting is interfering..?

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41373

You may also need to re-save your permalink settings after you add the parameter.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried

```
get_query_var('action');
```

Comment: Gave that a go. No luck. Defined it with.
 function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars[] = 'action';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );